# When is a functor of chain complexes triangulated?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\textsf{A}, \textsf{B}$ be abelian categories.
Let $F: \operatorname{Ch}(\textsf{A}) \to \operatorname{Ch}(\textsf{B})$ be an additive functor of chain complexes. If $F$ preserves chain homotopies it descends to a functor on the homotopy categories $\operatorname{HCh}(F): \operatorname{HCh}(\textsf{A}) \to \operatorname{HCh}(\textsf{B})$.

When is this functor triangulated?

Comment: Any additive functor induces a triangulated functor on the homotopy category of chain complexes, because, by definition, it commutes with taking cones.

Comment: @theL I see that this is the case if $F: \operatorname{A} \to \operatorname{B}.$ But why does a functor of chain complexes $F$ applied to a cone again yield a cone? It cannot be applied pointwise to $X_{j+1} \oplus Y_j$.

Comment: Any additive functor commutes with a finite direct sum.

Comment: @theL Is the cone a direct sum? The direct sum of $X[1]$ and $Y$ does not carry the same differential as the cone of a map $X \to Y$.

Comment: The cone is not a direct sum, but an additive functor commutes with all constructions that appear in the construction of the cone.

Comment: @theL I am sorry for asking again. If I calculate the component $(F(\operatorname{cone}(f))_n$ I take it that you mean this should be $F(X)[1]_n \oplus F(Y)_n$? I don't know how to conclude this since $F$ could mix different degrees of $\operatorname{cone}(f)$ together.

Comment: I think "the L"'s answer is coreect for functors of the form Ch(F), where F : A -> B is additive;  but otherwise you are right that additivity is not enough (as witnessed by, e.g., the connective cover functor from Ch(A) to itself)

Comment: @theL Please, stop spreading disinformation in the comments.